# Running MySQL WorkBench 6.3 on Mac 11.10.06 cannot connect through localhost and given error message "61"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

On my workbench I try to create a new connection with following setting
Connection Name: localhost
Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP
Host Name: localhost
Port: 3306
User Name: root

When I try to use "Test Connection" button, an error message show as following
Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root
can't connect to MySQL server on "127.0.0.1"(61)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql installation:

- Check your MySQL are opened on 127.0.0.1 IP.

  - Search on netstat command to verify if the 3306 port are opened to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 IP address.
  - If there isn't opened on some of these IPs, check my.cnf and change bind-address to 127.0.0.1
- If MySQL are opened on correct IP and port, update workbench, and also, try to re-type the IP address on workbench (I've check these process work on lot of cases).